# Implementing a UIViewController category

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to implement a category on my MainContainerViewController that returns the main instance:

In my .h:

```
@interface UIViewController(MainViewExtension)
/** Convience method for getting access to the MainContainerViewController instance */
- (MainContainerViewController *)mainContainerExtension;
@end
```

In my .m

```
@implementation UIViewController(MainViewExtension)
- (MainContainerViewController *)mainContainerExtension
{
    return (MainContainerViewController *)self;
}
@end
```

And so from some outside view controller, I do self.mainContainerExtension to access the instance, and there is only one instance declared, but it's not giving me the right instance.

```
NSLog(@"number of children:%i", [self.mainContainerExtension.childViewControllers count]);
```

This returns 0 even though it should be 3, so that's how I know it's not giving me the right results. Am I missing something?

**Edit:** The way I know it's not giving me the correct instance is because in the `viewDidLoad` of the `MainContainerViewController`, I have this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    appDelegate.notesViewController=[[NotesViewController alloc] init];
    appDelegate.notesViewController.mainContainer=self;
    [self addChildViewController: appDelegate.notesViewController];
}
```

Each `NotesViewController` has a property of type `MainContainerViewController`, so that I always have a way to access the `MainContainerViewController` from `NotesViewControllers`. But I just learned about categories and extensions, and I thought it might be easier to just implement a category that gives me access to the container view from whichever view I'm in, rather than having a property on every view controller. It's my first time, so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong with my category implementation, just not sure what it is.

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish a singleton?  Could you paste some code that shows a failed comparison?  That is, theExpectedHandleToVC != self.mainContainerExtension.  That compare or NSLog(@"%p", self) is a more direct way to test if it's working.

Comment: My output for `NSLog(@%@", self.mainContainerExtension)` is: `<NotesViewController: 0x6c4e5b0>`. Not really sure what that means though

Comment: It's the pointer to the instance.  Can you NSLog what you expect it to be?  In other words, what makes you think it's wrong?  A typical (non-tab bar) UIViewController should have 0 childViewControllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think instance method returning self can be useful.  Whatever object you would invoke that on: [someVC mainContainerExtension], you would already have the answer: it's someVC.

If each NotesViewController has a property for the containing VC, then aren't you all set?  As long as it's public in the NotesVC header:

```
MainContainerViewController *mainVC = [[MainContainerViewController] alloc] init ...];

// then, after the view loads
for (UIViewController *vc in mainVC.childViewControllers) {
  NSLog(@"%@", (NotesViewController *)vc.mainContainer);
}
```

Also note, unless there's only one NotesViewController in the app, the one getting assigned in appDelegate will be overwritten.  The handle in the appDelegate will be the last one allocated.